# REST's uniform interface

Tags: rest

I'm struggling a but with the concept of the uniform interface of REST. Does it not limit rich querying of data? For example, let's say I have a Movie entity:

```
Movie
======
id
directorId
categoryId
```

It would not be uncommon for me to build a DAO with the following methods, using foregin keys as filters:

```
MovieRepo.GetByDirector(int directoryId);
MovieRepo.GetByCategory(int category);
```

From my understanding of the uniform interface, the two following Get() methods are available to me:

```
IEnumerable<Movie> Get();
Movie Get(int id)
```

If I wanted to filter my query by directory or category with RESTful web service, am I out of luck?

```
IEnumerable<Movie> GetByCategory(int categoryId);
```

Obviously I would prefer not to retrieve all movies in my database, and then apply the filter client-side. Am I missing something? Or should I be sticking with RPC calls?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can map urls to resources as follows:

```
with GET
/movies/{movie_id}
/movies/{movie_id}/directors/{director_id}/
/movies/{movie_id}/categories/{category_id}/
```

then call whatever method you want for each url.

```
MovieRepo.GetByDirector(int directoryId); # in director controller
MovieRepo.GetByCategory(int category); # in category controller
MovieRepo.GetById(int movie_id); # in movie controller
```

Alternatively if you want to use a more filter like algorithm approach you can use an url as follows:

```
/movies?director=ridley&category=sci-fi
```

now you just have to take the query parameters and use them in your movie controller.